# Group and order based on multiple conditions and column values in SQL

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by, vertica

I have a table that has its Primary ID grouped under 3 categories and each category having an independent numeric value to it. I would want to create 3 ranks for each Primary ID (i.e. in each row) based on the below conditions.

1. If 'Overall Category' is High and all 3 categories are 'High', then Rank 1 value should be the value of Category that has highest value among the categories that are 'High'; Rank 2 should be the category with next highest value
2. If 'Overall Category' is High and 1 or 2 other categories are Mid, then Rank 1 should be the High Category irrespective of value. And Rank 2 should be the category that has higher value among the 'Mid' categories
3. Even if a 'Mid' category has higher value than 'High' category, in the Rank order, the 'High' category is given precedence.

Can such multiple grouping and ordering be done in SQL?

Giving a sample tale structure here.

```
Col 1   Col 2       Col 3   Col 4       Col 5   Col 6       Col 7   Col 8   Col 9   Col 10  Col 11
ID      Category A  Value A Category B  Value B Category C  Value C Overall Rank 1  Rank 2  Rank 3
1       High        69      Mid         51      Mid         61      High    A       C       B
2       Mid         80      Mid         90      Mid         65      Mid     B       A       C
3       High        62      Mid         59      Mid         85      High    A       C       B
4       High        71      High        89      Mid         90      High    B       A       C
5       High        67      High        90      Mid         80      High    B       A       C
6       Mid         70      High        54      Mid         71      High    B       C       A
7       Mid         67      Mid         89      Mid         91      Mid     C       B       A
8       Mid         61      High        74      High        50      High    B       C       A
9       Mid         75      Mid         95      Mid         90      Mid     B       C       A
10      Mid         64      Mid         65      Mid         84      Mid     C       B       A
```

Up to Column 8 is the input table. Last 3 columns is my requirement. Need suggestions please.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I was trying to make sense of what you say, but I'm afraid I don't manage. I am beginning to suppose that , in row 1 rank_1, rank_2 and rank_3 are not , in fact 'A', 'C' and 'B', but , somehow numbers. Can you put the numbers in , and the operands that make them up, at least for row 1, so I have an example of the rule(s)?

Comment: A, C and B as Rank 1, 2, and 3 correspond to the Value of A, B and C. A is Rank_1 because it's value is 69 > 61 > 51. Also, in Row 4: Ranks 1,2 and 3 are B, A and C; because, among "High" category, Value of B > Value of A. C is Rank 3 because it's Category is Mid even though it's value 90 > 89 > 71.

Answer (score 0):

Vertica is a relational database. If you think like a database "addict", you will naturally come to the best possible solution.

- replace repetitions in one row - like your a,b,c categories - with repetitions of rows - by transposing / un-pivoting
- use aggregations and aggregate functions and OLAP functios to get min, max, first, last and rank per group or partition.

And this is what you will see me doing. I add a 3-row table for the possible category values High, Mid and Low, and I add a 3-row category table: categories 'a','b', and 'c'. Then, I un-pivot, and take it from there.

I add two tables:

```
catrank:
rankid | rankname 
     1 | Low
     2 | Mid
     3 | High     

categ:
 catid | catname 
-------+---------
     1 | a
     2 | b
     3 | c
```

... and work with these, to create, for rows 1 and 4, for example:

```
 id | overall | category | rankid | val
----+---------+----------+--------+----
  1 | High    | a        |      3 |  69
  1 | High    | b        |      2 |  51
  1 | High    | c        |      2 |  61
  4 | High    | a        |      3 |  71
  4 | High    | b        |      3 |  89
  4 | High    | c        |      2 |  90
```

From this obtained table, which I name `unpivot`, as un-pivoting is what I do here, I then multiply `val` by `rankid` and use the result for the subsequent ranking.

The code to un-pivot as I did above is:

```
-- this is your input ....
WITH                                                                
input(
  id
, category_a
, value_a
, category_b
, value_b
, category_c
, value_c
, overall
, rank_1
, rank_2
, rank_3
) AS (
          SELECT 1,'High',69,'Mid',51,'Mid',61,'High','A','C','B'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Mid',80,'Mid',90,'Mid',65,'Mid','B','A','C'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'High',62,'Mid',59,'Mid',85,'High','A','C','B'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'High',71,'High',89,'Mid',90,'High','B','A','C'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'High',67,'High',90,'Mid',80,'High','B','A','C'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'Mid',70,'High',54,'Mid',71,'High','B','C','A'
UNION ALL SELECT 7,'Mid',67,'Mid',89,'Mid',91,'Mid','C','B','A'
UNION ALL SELECT 8,'Mid',61,'High',74,'High',50,'High','B','C','A'
UNION ALL SELECT 9,'Mid',75,'Mid',95,'Mid',90,'Mid','B','C','A'
UNION ALL SELECT 10,'Mid',64,'Mid',65,'Mid',84,'Mid','C','B','A'
)
,
-- category rank
catrank (rankid,rankname) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Low'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Mid'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'High'
)
,
-- category
categ(catid,category) AS (
          SELECT 1,'a'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'b'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'c'
)
,
here's the un-pivot, using a CROSS JOIN ..
unpivot AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , overall
  , category
  , rankid
  , CASE category
     WHEN 'a' THEN value_a
     WHEN 'b' THEN value_b
     WHEN 'c' THEN value_c
    END AS val
  FROM input
  CROSS JOIN categ
  JOIN catrank ON
    -- depending on the category you're cross-joined with,
    -- use a different "category_<x>" to join over ...
    CASE category
     WHEN 'a' THEN category_a
     WHEN 'b' THEN category_b
     WHEN 'c' THEN category_c
    END = rankname
  ORDER BY
    id
  , category
)
-- test query ...
SELECT * FROM unpivot ORDER BY 1,3
```

Now, I continue, selecting from `unpivot`, getting the descending `RANK()` of `rankid` multiplied by `val` (your `value_[abc]`)

```
, -- this is the continuation of the WITH clause above ...
with_rank AS (
SELECT
  id
, overall
, category
, rankid
, val
, rankid * val AS weight
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rankid * val DESC) AS weighted_rank
FROM unpivot
)
-- test query ...
SELECT * FROM with_rank
ORDER BY id, category
```

I get:

```
  id | overall | category | rankid | val | weight | weighted_rank
 ----+---------+----------+--------+-----+--------+--------------
   1 | High    | a        |      3 |  69 |    207 |             1
   1 | High    | b        |      2 |  51 |    102 |             3
   1 | High    | c        |      2 |  61 |    122 |             2
   4 | High    | a        |      3 |  71 |    213 |             2
   4 | High    | b        |      3 |  89 |    267 |             1
   4 | High    | c        |      2 |  90 |    180 |             3
```

, and I join that back with the `categ` table, to get the rank names ...

```
,
with_names AS (
  SELECT
    with_rank.*
  , categ.category AS catname
  , catrank.rankname
  FROM with_rank
  JOIN categ ON weighted_rank = catid
  JOIN catrank USING(rankid)
)
-- test query ...
SELECT * FROM with_names WHERE id in (1,4) ORDER BY 1,3;
```

Getting:

```
 id | overall | category | rankid | val | weight | weighted_rank | catname | rankname 
----+---------+----------+--------+-----+--------+---------------+---------+----------
  1 | High    | a        |      3 |  69 |    207 |             1 | a       | High
  1 | High    | b        |      2 |  51 |    102 |             3 | c       | Mid
  1 | High    | c        |      2 |  61 |    122 |             2 | b       | Mid
  4 | High    | a        |      3 |  71 |    213 |             2 | b       | High
  4 | High    | b        |      3 |  89 |    267 |             1 | a       | High
  4 | High    | c        |      2 |  90 |    180 |             3 | c       | Mid
```

Finally, pivot the obtained `with_names` table:

```
SELECT
  id
, MAX(CASE category WHEN 'a' THEN rankname END) AS category_a
, MAX(CASE category WHEN 'a' THEN val      END) AS value_a
, MAX(CASE category WHEN 'b' THEN rankname END) AS category_b
, MAX(CASE category WHEN 'b' THEN val      END) AS value_b
, MAX(CASE category WHEN 'c' THEN rankname END) AS category_c
, MAX(CASE category WHEN 'c' THEN val      END) AS value_c
, MAX(CASE category WHEN 'a' THEN catname  END) AS rank_1
, MAX(CASE category WHEN 'b' THEN catname  END) AS rank_2
, MAX(CASE category WHEN 'c' THEN catname  END) AS rank_3
FROM with_names
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
;
```

Getting:

```
  id | category_a | value_a | category_b | value_b | category_c | value_c | rank_1 | rank_2 | rank_3 
 ----+------------+---------+------------+---------+------------+---------+--------+--------+--------
   1 | High       |      69 | Mid        |      51 | Mid        |      61 | a      | c      | b
   2 | Mid        |      80 | Mid        |      90 | Mid        |      65 | b      | a      | c
   3 | High       |      62 | Mid        |      59 | Mid        |      85 | a      | c      | b
   4 | High       |      71 | High       |      89 | Mid        |      90 | b      | a      | c
   5 | High       |      67 | High       |      90 | Mid        |      80 | b      | a      | c
   6 | Mid        |      70 | High       |      54 | Mid        |      71 | c      | a      | b
   7 | Mid        |      67 | Mid        |      89 | Mid        |      91 | c      | b      | a
   8 | Mid        |      61 | High       |      74 | High       |      50 | c      | a      | b
   9 | Mid        |      75 | Mid        |      95 | Mid        |      90 | c      | a      | b
  10 | Mid        |      64 | Mid        |      65 | Mid        |      84 | c      | b      | a
```

Row 6 seems to differ, though. It could be that I would need to either change the weight of High, Mid, Low to something else than 1,2,3 or I need to evaluate the `overall` column, which I did not do here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Am more a novice, then. Am able to replicate your solution with the sample data!